# How can I write a paragraph with number points using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, text, html-lists

Using HTML I can add a ordered list points to a paragraph like this:

```
<ol>
  <li>Kopi</li>
  <li>Teh</li>
</ol>
```

How can I write orderred list point form in Flutter?

```
new Text(''),
```

Comment: are you looking something like this ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49626832/7924072

Comment: yes. but i want to number list, like this: 1. Kopi, 2.Teh.

Comment: do you have those names in list or add whatever real situation you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html 
code snippet

```
Html(
            data: """
    <ol>
      <li>Kopi</li>
      <li>Teh</li>
    </ol>
  """,
            //Optional parameters:
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            linkStyle: const TextStyle(
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart';
import 'package:html/dom.dart' as dom;

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Html(
            data: """
    <ol>
      <li>Kopi</li>
      <li>Teh</li>
    </ol>
  """,
            //Optional parameters:
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            linkStyle: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.redAccent,
              decorationColor: Colors.redAccent,
              decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
            ),
            onLinkTap: (url) {
              print("Opening $url...");
            },
            onImageTap: (src) {
              print(src);
            },
            //Must have useRichText set to false for this to work
            customRender: (node, children) {
              if (node is dom.Element) {
                switch (node.localName) {
                  case "custom_tag":
                    return Column(children: children);
                }
              }
              return null;
            },
            customTextAlign: (dom.Node node) {
              if (node is dom.Element) {
                switch (node.localName) {
                  case "p":
                    return TextAlign.justify;
                }
              }
              return null;
            },
            customTextStyle: (dom.Node node, TextStyle baseStyle) {
              if (node is dom.Element) {
                switch (node.localName) {
                  case "p":
                    return baseStyle.merge(TextStyle(height: 2, fontSize: 20));
                }
              }
              return baseStyle;
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```