# How to make a bullet point for every new line in a TextField?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make every new line start with a bullet point when the user presses return on the keyboard when using a TextField.

[tried to edit this answer to work for a TextField but couldn't get it to work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67910495/14307385)

[and then there's this but I don't know how to implement it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63212241/14307385)

[image]

Comment: do u mean bullet point inside TextField or just same row with your TextField ?

Comment: Oh, I guess it would be inside the TextField. Is that possible?  The goal is to make every new line start with a bullet point when the user presses return on the keyboard.

Comment: @LeenaMarie  I am trying to do the exactly same thing, were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do it

```
class _EditHealthEventDialogState extends State<EditHealthEventDialog> {
  TextEditingController notesController = TextEditingController();
  bool newLine = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    //notesController.text = widget.healthEvent['text'];
    notesController.addListener(() {
      print('___${notesController.text}');
      String note = notesController.text;
      if (note.isNotEmpty && note.substring(note.length - 1) == '\u2022') {
        print('newline');
        setState(() {
          newLine = true;
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          newLine = false;
        });
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      maxLines: 3,
      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
      controller: notesController,
      onChanged: (value) {
        Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {
          if (newLine) {
            return;
          }
          String note = notesController.text;
          if (note.isEmpty) {
            notesController.text = notesController.text + '\u2022';
            notesController.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
                TextPosition(offset: notesController.text.length));
          }
          if (note.isNotEmpty && note.substring(note.length - 1) == '\n') {
            notesController.text = notesController.text + '\u2022';
            notesController.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
                TextPosition(offset: notesController.text.length));
          }
        });
      },
      decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Notes', hintText: ''),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The getter 'healthEvent' isn't defined... what should I do here? I tried using ```notes``` from my data model

Comment: widget.healthEvent['text'] is just the initial text for that input. You can use a constant value instead or remove that line. I have updated the answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks. How do I make it so the first line also has a bullet point?

Comment: can you please help with this?

Comment: ok I will help you

Answer (score 1):

if you want it inside the TextField, you could set prefixIcon for TextField like this:

```
TextField(
   decoration: InputDecoration(
      fillColor: kGray08Color,
      prefixIconConstraints: BoxConstraints(
         minWidth: 20,
         minHeight: 10,
         maxHeight: 10,
         maxWidth: 20,
         ),
      prefixIcon: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10), child: ClipOval(child: Container( color: Colors.black, width: 5, height: 5)))
      isDense: true,
      ),
)
```

maybe you can adjust padding/ margin for your requirement

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried it but I'm still getting the same results. I updated my question with a picture and a link to another answer I tried