# TextFormField make first line have a bullet point

Tags: flutter, dart

Every new line has a bullet point but I need the first line to have one too. How can I achieve this with this code?

```
class _EditHealthEventDialogState extends State<EditHealthEventDialog> {
  TextEditingController notesController = TextEditingController();
  bool newLine = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    //notesController.text = widget.healthEvent['text'];
    notesController.addListener(() {
      print('___${notesController.text}');
      String note = notesController.text;
      if (note.isNotEmpty && note.substring(note.length - 1) == '\u2022') {
        print('newline');
        setState(() {
          newLine = true;
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          newLine = false;
        });
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      maxLines: 3,
      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
      controller: notesController,
      onChanged: (value) {
        Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {
          if (newLine) {
            return;
          }
          String note = notesController.text;
          if (note.isEmpty) {
            notesController.text = notesController.text + '\u2022';
            notesController.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
                TextPosition(offset: notesController.text.length));
          }
          if (note.isNotEmpty && note.substring(note.length - 1) == '\n') {
            notesController.text = notesController.text + '\u2022';
            notesController.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
                TextPosition(offset: notesController.text.length));
          }
        });
      },
      decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Notes', hintText: ''),
    );
  }
}
```

For context, I also asked this question - "How to make a bullet point for every new line in a TextField?"
[How to make a bullet point for every new line in a TextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72261750/how-to-make-a-bullet-point-for-every-new-line-in-a-textfield)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remembered:

```
notesController.text = '\u2022 ';
```